# Adding a combobox to a win32 API

Tags: c++, api, winapi, combobox

Ok first off this is homework but our teacher encourages us to go above and beyond what he actually gives us as an assignment.. So I want to learn how to add common dialog boxes. I chose to go with the combobox.

The problem is.. I have absolutely no idea where to start. I've google'd it and looked through the first page and a half with no help so I'm posting here :). The assignment was to do some simple things like display my name and draw some elipses and now I want to add a combobox..

Here is my code.

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: Jesse Moreland
Class: CST 238 GUI
Lab 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <string>

using std::string;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR lpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
     {
     static char szAppName[] = "ErrorSample";
     HWND           hwnd;
     HWND           comboBox;
     MSG            msg;    // Look how this struct is defined-see help/class notes NOW
     WNDCLASSEX     wndclass; 

          wndclass.cbSize        = sizeof(wndclass);
          wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
          wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
          wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
          wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
          wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance;
          wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

          wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
          wndclass.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH));
          wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
          wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
          wndclass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ERROR));

          RegisterClassEx (&wndclass);

//        PlaySound("C:\\Windows\\winsxs\\x86_microsoft-windows-speech-userexperience_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_1e1159f6aa0eb8c7\\Speech Off.wav",NULL, SND_FILENAME);

     hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,         // window class name
            "Jesse Moreland LAB 2 - Press Left or Right Mouse Button",           // window caption
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,     // window style
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial x position
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial y position
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial x size
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial y size
                    NULL,                    // parent window handle
                    NULL,                    // window menu handle
                    hInstance,               // program instance handle
                    NULL);                   // creation parameters

     ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

     UpdateWindow (hwnd);

     while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
          {
          TranslateMessage (&msg);
          DispatchMessage (&msg);
          }
     return (int) msg.wParam;
     }

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
                          WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
     {
     HDC  hdc;
     PAINTSTRUCT ps;
     RECT        rect;
     RECT        size;

     char * summer = "SUMMER IS COMING SOON!";
     char * leftOrRight = "Press Left or Right Mouse Button to make selection";

     switch (message)
         {

          case WM_PAINT:
                hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);

                GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect);

                GetWindowRect(hwnd, &size);

                HPEN hPenOld;

                //Draw ellipse
                HPEN hEllipsePen;
                COLORREF qEllipseColor;

                qEllipseColor = RGB(0, 0, 255);
                hEllipsePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, qEllipseColor);
                hPenOld =(HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hEllipsePen);

                Arc(hdc, 40, 40, 160, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                Arc(hdc, 50, 50, 180, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0);

                SelectObject(hdc, hPenOld);
                DeleteObject(hEllipsePen);

                TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, summer, strlen(summer));
                TextOut(hdc, 0, 20, leftOrRight, strlen(leftOrRight));



                EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
                return 0;

          case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
              return 0;

          case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
              return 0;

          case WM_DESTROY:
              PostQuitMessage(0);
              return 0;

         }

     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
     }
```

Where would I put the commands to make a combo box?

Answer (score 3):

Make a handler  for WM_CREATE, like

```
CASE WM_CREATE:
    CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "COMBOBOX", "MyCombo1", 
            CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
            0, 0, 50, 20, hwnd, 100, hInstance, NULL); // 100 = ID of this control
    CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "COMBOBOX", "MyCombo2", 
            CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
            100, 100, 50, 20, hwnd, 101, hInstance, NULL); // 101 = ID of this control
    return 0;
```

You can retrieve the window handle elsewhere in the dlgproc with

```
hEditCombo1 = GetDlgItem(hwnd, 100);
```

Comment: this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775793(v=vs.85).aspx) shows how to send messages to and how to receive notifications from the combobox

Comment: If you are going to make many handles for a program, you probably want to start using #define terms (e.g. #define IDC_MY_COMBO 100) instead of raw numbers...

Answer (score 0):

There is a Special message called `WM_CREATE`, which is called the first time the window is created. You can put your code there in order to have the combobox be created on startup.

About `WM_CREATE`

Sent when an application requests that a window be created by calling the CreateWindowEx or CreateWindow function. (The message is sent before the function returns.) The window procedure of the new window receives this message after the window is created, but before the window becomes visible.

```
switch(message){

...

case WM_CREATE: {
//create combobox

return 0;
}
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a reference.

**EDIT**

First, you'll Need to understand that *EVERY* control in Windows is a "window", so you'll create a combobox using `CreateWindow()` like

```
HWND hCombobox = CreateWindow(L"COMBOBOX", ...);
```

See [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-function.

Comment: I understand that but I don't have any idea how to create one?

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out with your help!! :).